# Opaque buttons in android app

Tags: android, colors, background, themes

I'm making an android app using the Theme.Holo.Light theme. When I assign a background colour, all controls on the page (i.e.: spinners and buttons) get 'splashed' with this colour.

Is there a way to make the controls unaffected by the background colour (or make them opaque)?

Thanks.